# Using symbols in an email

Tags: email, html-email

I'm creating an email, I have:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I need to include a copyright symbol, should I write it in code:

```
&copy;
```

Or use the symbol itself:

```
©
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `<meta charset="utf-8">` or some variation (what you have should be fine), **using `&copy;` is the safest bet**.

Even the most incapable email clients like Outlook (both old and new versions) should render a `©`.

Comment: Thanks, how about various & and $ signs in the text? Will I need to convert these? Of should I be ok?

Comment: In the same vein, `amp;` is probably the safest bet for rendering an ampersand (&). Curly quotes, trademark symbols, and non-english language chars like é are also ones to watch out for. I believe it's safe just to type the dollar sign `$` right in code.